Tkinter Threading Issue for Speed Type Test App
So I have read so many different issues on Threading and event managers for Tkinter, and I cannot find the solution to my issue. So right now I know my code is messy and I'm not worried about the tkinter organization yet, but I successfully created my timer and got it  on Canvas while in counts down, but I can't type in real time because my entry waits a full second with the timer before it shows up, creating a lag.
What specifically in my code am I doing wrong? I thought I made the thread correct.
#timer_display.py
from tkinter import *
from english_words import get_english_words_set


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = 60
        self.score = 0

    def countdown(self, parent):
        self.timecanvas = Canvas(parent, bg="black", width=500, height=100)
        self.timecanvas.pack()

    def tick(self):
        self.timecanvas.delete('all')
        self.timecanvas.create_text(145, 45, text=f"{self.timer}", fill="green", font=('Helvetica 55 bold'))
        self.timer -= 1
        self.timecanvas.update()

#main.py

import threading
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from timer_display import App
from threading import *
def start_timer():
    while root.timer != 0:
        root.timecanvas.after(1000, root.tick())

def time_thread():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=start_timer,daemon=True)
    thread.start()


def begin():
    global canvas, start_button
    canvas.destroy()
    frame = Frame(root,bg="white",height=100,width=500)
    frame2 = Frame(root,bg="white",height=100,width=500)
    root.countdown(frame2)
    start_button.destroy()
    start_button = Button(root, bg="white", image=start_but, command=time_thread)
    start_button.pack()
    input = Entry(root, bg="white", width=50, fg="black")
    input.pack()
    frame2.pack()

root = App()
root.title("Typing Speed App")
root.config(padx=10, pady=10)
root.minsize(500,500)
root.maxsize(900,900)
root.geometry("900x900")
display = PIL.Image.open('racetrack.jpg', mode='r').resize((800, 800))
trackpic = ImageDraw.Draw(display)
font = ImageFont.load_default(20)
trackpic.text((75,0),"Welcome to Type Timer App!",font=font,fill=(0,0,0),font_size=250)
trackpic.text((305,700),"Click Start to Begin!",font=font,fill=(255,255,255))
canvas = Canvas(root,bg="white")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(display)
start_but = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('start_button.jpg', mode='r').resize((150, 150)))
canvas.config(height=800,width=800)
start_button = Button(root,bg="white",image=start_but,command=begin)
start_button.config(height=150,width=150)
start_button.place(x=350,y=520)
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor=NW)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()


why do you use while root.timer != 0: to run root.timecanvas.after(1000, root.tick())? it may create many processes.

after() (similar to Button(command=...) and Thread(target=...)) needs function's name without () like .after(1000, root.tick) - and it will later use () to run this function. Your code works like result = root.tick and .after(1000, result) - because tick() doesn't use return so it returns None and you have .after(1000, None)

I didn't run your code but I expect it could run .after without threading because tick() doesn't need long time to run code. Shortly: you don't need threading at all.

after() (similar to Button(command=...) and Thread(target=...) and root.bind(...)) needs function's name without () like
.after(1000, root.tick)

and tkinter will later use () to run this function.
Your code works like
result = root.tick() 
....after(1000, result)

because tick() doesn't use return so it returns None and you have
.after(1000, None)

Other problem can be while-loop
while root.timer != 0:
    root.timecanvas.after(1000, root.tick())

because this loop runs all time so it can run hundreds times in every second and it may start hundreds tick() - and it may block all your code.
But you don't need threading at all.
Your tick() doesn't need long time so it doesn't block tkinter so it can run without threading
You should run after(..., tick()) inside tick() to execute it again.
    def tick(self):

        # ... code ...
        
        if self.timer > 0:  # to makes sure it is not negative
            self.timecanvas.after(1000, self.tick)


This is full working code without threading but with cleaner code.
I don't have your images so I use Image.new to generate images, and I uses some methods to center text automatically.
# [Text anchors - Pillow (PIL Fork) 10.3.0 documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html#text-anchors)

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# --- classes ---

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = 10
        self.score = 0
        self.timer_started = False
        self.timer_text_id = None
        
    def countdown(self, parent):
        self.timecanvas = tk.Canvas(parent, bg="black", width=500, height=100)
        self.timecanvas.pack()
        
        # create empty text
        if not self.timer_text_id:
            self.timer_text_id = self.timecanvas.create_text(250, 50, fill="green", font=('Helvetica 55 bold'), anchor='center')
            
    def tick(self):
        # replace text without deleting all elements
        self.timecanvas.itemconfigure(self.timer_text_id, text=self.timer)
        
        self.timer -= 1
        
        if self.timer >= 0:  # to makes sure it is not negative, use >= instead of > to display 0
            self.timecanvas.after(1000, self.tick)

    def start_timer(self):
        if not self.timer_started:  # stop running again
            self.timer_started = True
            self.tick() # run at once
        
# --- functions ---

def begin():
    global canvas, start_button
    
    # remove previous content
    canvas.destroy()
    start_button.destroy()

    # create new content
    start_button = tk.Button(root, bg="white", image=start_button_image, command=root.start_timer)
    start_button.pack()
    
    input = tk.Entry(root, bg="white", width=50, fg="black")
    input.pack()

    root.countdown(root)

# --- main ---

root = App()
root.title("Typing Speed App")
root.config(padx=10, pady=10)
root.minsize(500,500)
root.maxsize(900,900)
root.geometry("900x900")

font = ImageFont.load_default(20)

# ----

image_width  = 150
image_height = 150

#start_button_pil = Image.open('start_button.jpg').resize((image_width, image_height))
start_button_pil = Image.new('RGB', (image_width, image_height), color='red')
start_button_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(start_button_pil)

# center text on image
pos_x = image_width//2
pos_y = image_height//2
anchor = 'mm'  # width-height: middle-middle
start_button_draw.text((pos_x, pos_y), "START", font=font, fill=(0,0,0), anchor=anchor)

start_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(start_button_pil)
start_button = tk.Button(root, bg="white", image=start_button_image, command=begin, width=image_width, height=image_height)
start_button.place(x=350, y=520)

# ----

image_width  = 800
image_height = 400

#racetrack_pil = Image.open('racetrack.jpg').resize((image_width, image_height))
racetrack_pil = Image.new('RGB', (image_width, image_height), color='green')
racetrack_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(racetrack_pil)

# center text on image
pos_x = image_width//2
pos_y = 5
anchor = 'mt'  # width-height: top-middle
racetrack_draw.text((pos_x, pos_y), "Welcome to Type Timer App!", font=font, fill=(0,0,0), anchor=anchor)

# center text on image
pos_x = image_width//2
pos_y = image_height//2
anchor = 'mm'  # width-height: middle-middle
racetrack_draw.text((pos_x, pos_y), "Click Start to Begin!", font=font, fill=(255,255,255), anchor=anchor)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white", width=image_width, height=image_height)
canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(racetrack_pil)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor='nw')

# ----

root.mainloop()


Thank you so much so after not using threading and changing self.timer > 0 and running the after(1000, self.tick) inside its function, I can type in real time! I'm at the end of a Udemy Python course and I'm making a Portfolio and this is one of my apps. I feel so dumb because I spent 2 days stuck on this and it really discouraged me.

I think you had example of XY Problem. See page The XY Problem

I appreciate you taking the time to help me! I'm going to try to clean everything up and finish the App today hopefully.

@JesseJohnson Did this answer your question? Cause if it did, it's good practice to mark the answer as accepted with the checkmark button.
